# AWS config option source_profile results in AccessDenied when calling AssumeRole operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, config, aws-cli

I am setting up AWS cli on Windows 10 configuration using `credentials` and `config` files. In the `config` file I define a `config_profile` and in it use `source_profile` to link it with the profile defined in `credentials`.

When I run `aws configure list --profile config_profile` I am getting:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: Access denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you granted permission for the switch to take place?  Check out https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_permissions-to-switch.html.

> When you create a role for cross-account access, you establish trust
>   from the account that owns the role and the resources (trusting
>   account) to the account that contains the users (trusted account). To
>   do this, you specify the trusted account number as the Principal in
>   the role's trust policy. That allows potentially any user in the
>   trusted account to assume the role. To complete the configuration, the
>   administrator of the trusted account must give specific groups or
>   users in that account permission to switch to the role.
>
> To grant a user permission to switch to a role, you create a new
>   policy for the user or edit an existing policy to add the required
>   elements.
>
> A policy that grants a user permission to assume a role must include a
>   statement with the Allow effect on the following:
>
> ```
> The sts:AssumeRole action
>
> The Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the role in a Resource element
> ```

For example:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-ID-WITHOUT-HYPHENS:role/Test*"
  }
}
```

Also see

- [How enable access to AWS STS AssumeRole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337079/how-enable-access-to-aws-sts-assumerole)
- https://medium.com/@ngocson2vn/how-to-fix-the-error-an-error-occurred-accessdenied-when-calling-the-assumerole-operation-e85f0152daca