# How to get temporary security credential from AWS to access s3 bucket and upload files by using java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I referred to this https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-s3-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/AuthUsingTempFederationTokenJava.md link but it shows a profile error that the profile file should not be null.
another I referred this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/AuthUsingTempSessionToken.html even this doesn't work for me. any suggestion?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both links you need to follow the instructions and not just copy/paste the code. The profile is null, because you most probably haven't created a ~/.aws/credentials file.

The process to test the code should be:

- Create an IAM user, assign the appropriate permissions and create access keys
- Add a profile to the ~/aws/credentials file with the keys of the user
- Use the profile like `new ProfileCredentialsProvider("app-1-development")` in your code.

Please also refer [here](https://aws.amazon.com/ar/blogs/developer/secure-local-development-with-the-profilecredentialsprovider/)

Comment: I already created a user, got its accesskey and secretID, assigned the policy to it, everything was already done, even I tried to just upload file using accesskey and secretID and that was working, but I didn't understand the concept of the profile, I mean like how do I get profile and the location of ~/aws/credential or need to create that location where my credential file should be stored?

Comment: AWSSecurityTokenService stsClient = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(clientRegion)     .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey))).build();
AssumeRoleRequest roleRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest().withRoleArn(roleARN).withRoleSessionName(roleSessionName);
AssumeRoleResult roleResponse = stsClient.assumeRole(roleRequest);
Credentials sessionCredentials = roleResponse.getCredentials();        current code im using

Comment: error it shows User: arn:aws:iam:XXXXX:user/ is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam:XXXXX:role

Comment: You are missing a trust relationship (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337079/how-enable-access-to-aws-sts-assumerole)